# Navicat Premium doesn't show/list tables in postgres database schema

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, navicat

I have a local instance of postgres in my Windows machine, when I explore the databases and schemas in PgAdmin4 I can see every table and make queries and etc.

[image]

But when I connect to this same postgres instance with same host, user and password with Navicat Premium it only show me the databases but I cannot see the tables in them, but if I do a query I get the result.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Postgres are you using? Please add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same problem today after upgrading to Postgres 12. An update of Navicat to the current latest version (12.1.27) solved the issue for me.